# How do I view all messages from several folder in single view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have my Outlook 2010 configured with rules which will send mails from different users in specific folders.

Is there any option to view all the mails received today in any way? Any particular folder or view?

Comment: So after the messages have been delivered to different folders, you're looking for a way to view all of the messages received since midnight consolidated in one window?  Are you looking for full access to the messages from there (treat them as if they are all in the inbox), or do you just need some form of summary information?

Answer (score 1):

[Create a Search Folder](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/Create-a-Search-Folder-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5?CorrelationId=0f1486a0-bfbf-44a8-8b9b-97a93ee0ebed&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA)  "A Search Folder is a virtual folder that provides a view of all email items that match specific search criteria."

This is specific to the question. [Tip 913: Count the Total Number of Messages Received Today](http://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/count-total-number-messages-received-today/)

To get the count first there is a search.

1. Right click on the Search folder and choose New Search folder.
2. Choose Custom search folder from the bottom of the list.
3. Click the Choose button.
4. Click the Browse button if you want to limit the search to specific folders.
5. Enter a name and click the Criteria button.
6. On the General tab, select Received as the field and Today as the Condition.